# SQL Server - Temporal Table - Storage costs

Tags: sql-server, temporal-tables

Are there any information on the internet, where I can verify how much storage costs are for temporal tables?

Will the server create a the full hardcopy of the row/tuple that was modified? Or will the server use a reference/link to the original values of the master table that are not modified?

**Example:**

- I have a row with 10 columns = storage 100 KB.
- I change one value of that row, two times.
- I now have two rows in the historical table after changes.
- Is the storage cost for the master and historical table then ~300KB?

Thanks for every hint!

Ragards

Comment: It is not a comprehensive storage guide but there is at least one warning about storage [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-table-considerations-and-limitations) ... *While temporal tables support blob data types ... they will incur significant storage costs ... care should be taken when using these data types*

Comment: If someone provides an answer and it's "too costly" for you, what alternatives are you considering? Is there a reason you cannot setup experiments and *measure* these things yourself?

Comment: i use currently a selft build legacy solution from sql server 2005, where i copy only the value of the changes column and the column name in a dedicated table. I plan to replace this legacy construct with the temporal table feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will the server creates a the full hardcopy of the row/tuple that was
>   modified? Or will the server use a reference/links to the original
>   values of the master table that are not modified?

Here is the cite of the book [Pro SQL Server Internals
by Dmitri Korotkevitch](https://www.apress.com/it/book/9781484219638) that ansers your question:

> In a nutshell, each temporal table consists of two tables — the 
>   current table  with the current data, and a history table  that stores
>   old versions of the rows. **Every time you modify or delete data in
>   the current table, SQL Server adds an original version of those rows
>   to the history table**.
>
> A current table should always have a `primary key` defined. Moreover,
>   both current and history tables should have two  `datetime2`  columns,
>   called  period columns, that indicate the lifetime of the row. SQL
>   Server populates these columns automatically based on transaction
>   start time when the new versions of the rows  were created. When a row
>   has been modified several times in one transaction, SQL Server does
>   not preserve uncommitted intermediary row versions in the history
>   table.
>
> SQL Server places the history tables in a default filegroup, creating
>   non-unique  clustered indexes on the two  datetime2  columns that
>   control row  lifetime. It does not create any other  indexes on the
>   table.
>
> In both the Enterprise and Developer Editions, history tables use
>   page `compression` by default.

So it's not

> reference/links to the original values of the master table

Previous row version is just copied as it is into historical table on every mofification.